# Read, Transpose Big Matrix and Save

Tags: python, c++, file, file-io, transpose

You have a very big matrix saved in a csv file. You want to transpose it and save it into another file. You can not load all the data into memory at one time. How can you do it?

I think we can read a row from the file and transpose it to a column and write the column into a file. Reading and transposing rows to column is ok to me, but I don't know how to write into a file column by column. Anyone could implement?

Comment: One option would be to read the original file column-wise, however that may take a while depending on the size of the csv as you would have to read each row x times, where x is the number of columns it has. Im sure there is a better solution that someone might be nice enough to reveal.

Comment: Just load it into memory anyway.  The operating system will do a far better job at managing virtual memory than any scheme you could come up with trying to stay within the limits of physical RAM.

Comment: What's the target language? You have both python and C++ here. Is it a more general question? Are you interested in performance? Transposing a very large matrix would result in a **lot** of cache misses and long execution times for example.

Comment: @deeiip Interviewer?  This is stack overflow, not code golf... if we're talking about contrived puzzles this is the wrong website.  This is the "how would a professional solve this problem" site, not the "help me get a job and do my work for me" site.

Comment: @J... Interview questions are very common on this site, do a search if you don't believe me.

Comment: I still don't see anything about an interview - I see a question about how to solve a programming problem; and a pretty weak question at that.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I'll give you a hint:

```
ol = or x C + oc (consider arr[or][oc])
```

It is to be moved to new location nl in the transposed matrix, say nl = A[nr][nc], or in C/C++ terms

`nl = nr x R + nc` (R - column count, C is row count as the matrix is transposed)
nr = oc and nc = or, so replacing these for nl,

`nl = oc x R + or` 
So,

```
ol     = or x C     + oc
ol x R = or x C x R + oc x R
       = or x N     + oc x R    (from the fact R * C = N)
       = or x N     + (nl - or) --- from [eq 1]
       = or x (N-1) + nl
```

OR,

```
nl = ol x R - or x (N-1)
```

the values of nl and ol never go beyond N-1, so considering modulo division on both the sides by (N-1), we get the following based on properties of congruence,

```
nl mod (N-1) = (ol x R - or x (N-1)) mod (N-1)
             = (ol x R) mod (N-1) - or x (N-1) mod(N-1)
             = ol x R mod (N-1), since second term evaluates to zero
nl = (ol x R) mod (N-1), since nl is always less than N-1
```

So now you may just read one element at a time and put it to its correct position in the corresponding transposed matrix.

Comment: Gotta say that I don't see how you really avoid constructing a transposed matrix in memory. Maybe if you can use a more "orthodox" notation, it's really hard to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The program 'transpose' from https://github.com/micans/reaper may help here. It loads the matrix into memory as a single string, then writes the transposed result to file without creating it in memory. Hence the memory overhead is absolutely limited to size of the matrix on disk (uncompressed). The program can read/write compressed data, and the row and cell separators are customisable (default '\n' and '\t'). In a simple test on a 60460 x 4671 matrix (compressed size 125M) it used about 20 times less memory than Python + pandas, and about 12 times less memory than R, in both cases being approximately 13 times faster. An upside is that no rounding or truncating of data happens, every field is copied as a sequence of bytes.